# Get Contents (URL) and Run Pregmatch all, then Print out results as specified

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I am trying to scrape a craigslist search for apartments.

Code:

```
$city = 'saltlakecity';
$rooms = '';
$query = '';
$sdate ='';
$url = 'http://'.$city.'.craigslist.org/search/apa?bedrooms='.$rooms.'&query='.$query.'&sale_date='.$sdate.'';
$base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$resultspage = file_get_contents($url);

// use DOMDocument and DOMXpath
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($resultspage);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$rows = $xpath->query('//p[@class="row"]'); // get all rows
foreach($rows as $entries) { // loop each row
$entry = array();
$entry['title'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="pl"]/a', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$entry['link'] = 'http://' . $base_url . $xpath->query('./a[@class="i"]', $entries)->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
$entry['price'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[1]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$location = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[2]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
$loc = str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $location);
$entry['location'] = $loc;
$entry['seller'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/a', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;

$url2 = $entry['link'];
$listingpage = file_get_contents($url2);
$dom2 = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom2->loadHTML($listingpage);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath2 = new DOMXpath($dom2);
$entry['address'] = $xpath2->query('./div[@class="mapAndAttrs"]/div[3]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

$text_node = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
// remove "/"" and "-""  | explode by space | filter space (now, its left by 2 values: bedroom and size)
$text_node = array_filter(explode(' ', str_replace(array('/', '-'), '', $text_node)));
$entry['bedrooms'] = array_shift($text_node); // bedroom
$entry['dimensions'] = array_shift($text_node); // dimensions

$data[] = $entry; // after gathering necessary items, assign inside
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

****UPDATE: I am now trying to get scrape the scraped link, for the address of the property****

What I am trying to accomplish is have a pregmatch find The title, URL, how many bedrooms, the city it is in, and also price then print it out. However, if I simply put "$matches" the page puts array. If I put the code above, the page loads white.

Can somebody please check out my code and tell me what I might be doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I humbly suggest use a proper tool (an HTML Parser) by using `DOMDocument` with `DOMXpath` instead of regular expressions. Example:   [**`Sample Fiddle`**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/a3Z02N#)

```
$city = 'saltlakecity';
$url = "http://".$city.".craigslist.org/search/apa/?bedrooms=2&hasPic=1&query=";
$base_url = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$resultspage = file_get_contents($url);

// use DOMDocument and DOMXpath
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($resultspage);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$rows = $xpath->query('//p[@class="row"]'); // get all rows
foreach($rows as $entries) { // loop each row
    $entry = array();
    $entry['title'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="pl"]/a', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $entry['link'] = 'http://' . $base_url . $xpath->query('./a[@class="i"]', $entries)->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
    $entry['price'] = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[1]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $text_node = $xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    // remove "/"" and "-""  | explode by space | filter space (now, its left by 2 values: bedroom and size)
    $text_node = array_filter(explode(' ', str_replace(array('/', '-'), '', $text_node)));
    $entry['bedrooms'] = array_shift($text_node); // bedroom
    $entry['dimensions'] = array_shift($text_node); // dimensions

    $address = @$xpath->query('./span[@class="txt"]/span[@class="l2"]/span[@class="pnr"]/small', $entries)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $address = str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $address);
    $entry['address'] = $address;

    $data[] = $entry; // after gathering necessary items, assign inside
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Should output this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Beautiful Spacious Sandy Home for rent
            [link] => http://saltlakecity.craigslist.org/apa/4605359897.html
            [price] => $2050
            [bedrooms] => 6br
            [dimensions] => 3710ft²
            [address] =>  10251 Snow Iris Way, Sandy
        )
    and many more ...
```

Comment: @user3259138 i revised some code, if you're dealing with HTML elements always consider an HTML Parser (`simple_html_dom` is also okay), this is the recommended way to situations like this.

Comment: So I actually have a question for you to expand on this.

Comment: I would like to take the entry['link'] and then construct another url to scrape like "http://'.$city.'.craigslist.org'.$entry['link']", then grab the actual address that is right under the map. I tried setting up a whole new domdoc and domxpath and everything, but I can't quite figure out how to get the address and make it part of the existing array of 'data'. Suggestions?

Comment: @user3259138 just create another instance of dom document and xpath using that url inside the loop. from there, just use the same logic on the answer (the xpath queries) in getting your desired data. of course don't expect this to be fast, since you have many rows.

Comment: Okay, the code is now updated. I currently get 'Notice: Trying to get property of non-object' error. Suggestions on how I can correctly scrape the entry['link'] for the address and add the scraped address to the existing data array?

Comment: @user3259138 are you sure its `<div class="mapAndttrs">`? i checked out a url and it doesn't seem to exist. `http://saltlakecity.craigslist.org/apa/4605359897.html`

Comment: @user3259138 that div is unreliable, sometimes it exists, on some posts it does not. maybe you should use `<h2 class="postingtitle">` instead: `query('//h2[@class="postingtitle"]')` instead, then regex the values inside the parethesis `()`

Comment: Yeah. I was able to figure it out. It came down to my own syntactical error. I really appreciate you taking the time to assist me. You have been outstanding.